# Switching monitor input from Windows PC to Mac Mini fails if PC is on

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, mac-mini

I have a Windows PC¹ and a Mac Mini² both connected to two monitors³:

```
  +----------------------+
  |                      |
  | +---------+       +---------+
  | | Monitor |       | Monitor |
  | |    1    |       |    2    |
  | +---------+       +---------+
  |      |  |                |
  |      |  |                |
  +---+  |  +------------+   |
      |  |               |   |
MiniDP|  |HDMI         DP|   |HDMI
    +---------+       +---------+
    | Mac     |       | Windows |
    | Mini    |       | PC      |
    +---------+       +---------+
```

When I want to use the Windows PC, I switch Monitor 1 to DisplayPort and Monitor 2 to HDMI. And when I want to use the Mac Mini, I switch Monitor 1 to HDMI and Monitor 2 to DisplayPort.

This mostly works. However, when both computers are on, and I try to switch from the Windows PC to the Mac Mini (by switching Monitor 1 to HDMI and Monitor 2 to DisplayPort), the monitors briefly show a black screen then switch back to the previous input (DP on Monitor 1 and HDMI on Monitor 2). **This only happens when switching from the Windows PC to the Mac Mini**. If I turn on the Mac Mini first, then turn on the Windows PC, the monitors continue to show the input from the Mac Mini. But if I switch to the Windows PC, I can't switch back.

The only workaround I found to switch back to the Mac Mini is to make the Windows PC sleep, or disable Monitor 1 with <kbd>Win+P</kbd>->"Second screen only" (which switches Monitor 1 to the Mac Mini), then disable the other one with <kbd>Win+P</kbd>->"PC screen only" (which switches Monitor 2 to the Mac Mini).

Is there anything I can do to make it work correctly?

¹ Lenovo ThinkStation P300, graphics card is Quadro K620

² Late 2014

³ Lenovo T2254p and Lenovo T2324p

Comment: Is the Mac Mini on when you try this? Eitherway, it seems like the Monitor favours the DP connection over the HDMI connection. You're stuck, unless your monitor lets you turn off auto source changing.

Comment: @djsmiley2k Yes, the Mac Mini is on. And no, it's not a preference of one source over another: Monitor 2 has the exact same issue except that it refuses to switch from HDMI to DP if the Windows PC (connected to HDMI) is on.

Comment: So it prefers HDMI on monitor 2 as well?

Comment: @djsmiley2k it prefers whatever is connected to the Windows PC. DP on Monitor 1 and HDMI on Monitor 2. But **only when switching**. If I turn on the Mac Mini first, then turn on the Windows PC, the monitors continue to show the input from the Mac Mini. But if I switch to the Windows PC, I can't switch back.

Comment: Ok, make that clearer in your question. :) -- Weird!!

Comment: @djsmiley2k I edited the question. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: @imgx64 I have the same issue, have you found any solution?